# Dapper in Metro apps

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, dapper

Is there any way to include Dapper in metro apps? 
It relies on System.Data which is left out in WinRT.
If not is there any similar framework which can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to include Dapper in metro apps?

No. As you observe, the lack of `System.Data` is pretty much a show-stopper, however in addition WinRT also omits meta-programming support, so the entire core would need to be re-written to use regular (i.e. slow) reflection. There are some elaborate hoops you can jump through to get around this, but without `System.Data` it seems a lost cause.

Basically, the intent with WinRT (as I understand it) is to consume your data from things like web-services, the classic "smart client" rather than "rich client" model.

So you might consider:

- server (full .NET)

  - using "dapper" for data-access
  - exposing some call/serialization protocol
- client (.NET for Windows Store apps, or whatever the term is today)

  - consuming some call/serialization protocol

*Strictly speaking*, you *can* IIRC break all the rules and just reference .NET anyway, but that won't pass any MS validation, and won't be a proper <s>metro</s> Windows Store application.

Comment: @user1104494 Since Marc's answer appeared to answer you question you should mark it as answered w/ the check mark. It's a great feature of Stack Overflow which helps keep things neat and tidy.